# questions about random variables, if the following statement is true and why

Tags: random-variable

[image]

questions about random variables, if the following statement is true and why

Comment: Hint as per this community's policy on homework questions (which it appears so): If $X$ is a random variable, $F_X(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. Does $F_Y(x)$ enjoy the same property?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.